# How to set the background color of the view while animating from one page to another in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my `UIPageViewController` I want to set different background color while dragging from one page to another. So my default color will be there but will show different color on different index transition. At the moment under my `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` I am getting the index number of the current page:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
            let index = orderedViewControllers.index(of: firstViewController) {
            viewControllerDelegate?.pageViewController(pageViewController: self, didUpdatePageIndex: index)

            if index == 0 {

                (parent as? MainViewController)?.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            else if index == 1 {

                (parent as? MainViewController)?.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }

        }


    }
```

But how can I set the color in between them.

Comment: Just set the window background color to your required color.

Comment: what do u mean by that ?

Comment: `UIWindow` background color.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

*If you want to set the appearance then add the following line:*

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyViewController class], nil];
```

Comment: what appearence??

Comment: It is just like colours.

Answer (score 0):

Your color in Array as this

```
  let Array: [(name: String, color: UIColor)] = [("Red", UIColor.red), ("Blue",     UIColor.blue),("Green", UIColor.green)]

  print( Array[index]) // index is Your array indexNumber.
```

And pass this array value in background color

```
  (parent as? MainViewController)?.container.backgroundColor = [Pass this array index color]
```